# WPF - Image source in a Style in another assembly

Tags: wpf, image

I have a library with some WPF Styles and another application that references this library and it styles, but I'm having a problem with an Image style. I set the **Source** property in the style with an image in the same library, but when I run my application it returns a **XAML Markup error** saying it didn't found the image.

**Library/Styles/MyStyles.xaml** (the .png is in **Library/Resources/**)

```
<Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="MyToolTipImage">
    <Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="SmartToolTipImage">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0, 0, 10, 0" />
    <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Library;component/Resources/question_icon.png" />
</Style>
```

**MyProject/View/ConfigView.xaml**

```
    <Image
        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
        Style="{library:MyStyleRef ResourceKey=MyToolTipImage}"
        ToolTip="{DynamicResource foldersReloadToolTip}"/>
```

The error returned is **Could not find the resource question_icon.png**. Also, all others styles that I have defined in this .xaml works well, like buttons and datagrids.

Comment: The Build Action of the image file is set to Resource?

Comment: pack://application:,,,/Library/Resources/question_icon.png ? Because it's not a referenced assembly, it's the one that contains the resource

Comment: you can also ditch the "pack://" etc. and use a relative path from where you're trying to reference it from.

Comment: @Clemens é test it as Content, Resource and Embedded Resource. All returned the same error

Comment: Should be Resource, nothing else.

Comment: @Marsh I used this "pack..." because this is the way I load resources in the C# ViewModel of this same Library and it works. I also tried using **"Library;Component/Resources/question_icon.png"** and it didn't work also

Comment: Using `/Library;component/` is correct here, since the Style maybe applied from inside a different assembly. However, make sure `Library` is the correct name of the library assembly.

Comment: However, it is unclear what `library:MyStyleRef` is supposed to be. You would usually include a ResourceDictionary from a different assembly via the `MergedDictionaries` property of a "local" ResourceDictionary, and then simply write `Style="{StaticResource MyToolTipImage}"`.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by referencing this way

```
/Library;Component/Resources/question_icon.png
```

With the first **/** and the **Component** with a capital C. Also, the image must be have the Build Action set as **Resource**.